# Custom authentication in suds library (Python)

Tags: python, soap, suds

I need to access a SOAP server with WSDL where the authentication is done by sending two parameters, UserId and AccessToken. I tried this way:
    token = UsernameToken(
        UserId,
        AccessToken
        )
    token.setnonce()
    token.setcreated()

```
security = Security()
security.tokens.append(token)


client = Client(URL)
client.set_options(wsse=security)
```

and suds throwed this error

```
URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known>
```

How do I add this parameters to my request? Or am I doing something else wrong?

Comment: It would help if you provided your WSDL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the parameters are supposed to part of a header, you can do it that way:

```
header = client.factory.create('HeaderNameInWSDL')
header.UserId = 'foo'
header.AccessToken = 'bar%n3'
client.set_options(soapheaders=header)
```

Then do you stuff.